# Use Half of QCView

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsview, quartz-composer

I feel like this should be a simple issue, but I can't figure it out.

I have a QCView in my app. When I display it normally, it looks like this: [QCView](http://ariweinstein.com/QCView1.png). But, I only want to see the top half of it, because on the bottom half I want to see what is on the NSView under it. When I try to do this, I get this: [QCView Half](http://ariweinstein.com/QCView2.png). How can I get it to show only the top half, and not use the middle as an anchor?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you currently trying to do it?

Comment: Setting the QCView's frame's height to half what it should be. :p

Comment: Without sitting behind QC I can't be sure, but isn't there some "Fill to Height/Fill to Width" checkbox?